# Position fixed and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: "touch" breaks page on IOS8

Tags: javascript

In IOS 8 if we have position:fixed wrapper and inside content of the wrapper is scrollable and dynamic then IOS8 encounters an issue in compliance of smooth scrolling behaviour which is what: that  your page stops to scroll when you reaches at the end and still try to scroll up or down.

The solution to this problem is : Always makes the scrollbar to be in middle i.e not always at top or not always at bottom:

```
  $(scrollable_Wrapper).bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
         $(scrollable_Wrapper).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()-1)
       }else if(  $(this).scrollTop()===0){
         $(scrollable_Wrapper).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()+1);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Dont post code in comments. Edit your question to include your code. Also it is best if you provide a fiddle to demonstrate your problem